# What is the reason for the garbage value printed at the beginning?

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a program which will do two things

1. get a number between 0 to 10(10 is not included,so values should be less than 10),separate them and store them in an array
2. print the array for each number

For that purpose I wrote an if-else block which will initialize an array each time exactly according to the size of the current integer value which is denoted by variable called `num`

Meaning that if I have a number of single digit it will create an array of one element, but if the number is two digits long, it will create an array of two elements, etc. But whenever I run the code, I get some garbage value printed at the beginning.

What might be the reason for that and how to solve this issue?

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int mirror(int *arr,int num,int i);
int main(){

    int num = 0;
    int range = 1;
    int *arr;
    while(num<10){
       int i=0;
       if(num<(int)pow(10,range)){

           arr=(int *)malloc(range*sizeof(int));
       }else{
           range+=1;
           arr=(int *)malloc(range*sizeof(int));
       }

       mirror(arr,num,i);
       for(i=range-1;i>=0;i--){
          printf("%d ",arr[i]);
       }
       printf("\n");
       num++;
    }

}

int mirror(int *arr,int num,int i){

     if(num == 0){
         return 0;
     }
     arr[i] = num%10;
     mirror(arr,num/10,++i);

}
```

Comment: You're leaking memory horribly.  And that might be leading to your odd values; you may not be initializing the new array properly.  Normally, you'd be using `realloc()` in the `else` statement.

Comment: using realloc gives the same output :(

Comment: Yeah; you're leaking memory, but I'm not sure what's going wrong with the code (yet).

Comment: why all the downvotes for? did i do anything wrong or violate any rule ? i just asked a question

Comment: The only thing that people might find surprising is the image instead of just a text copy of the example output.  However, that really doesn't warrant a down-vote in my book.

Comment: downvotes are frustrating ,it takes patience to earn reputation these days you know :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're not setting `arr[i]` to anything in the base case in mirror function. And if there isn't any use of the return value of the function, why are you making it return anything?
Either make it `void` or if you've to return value from it, at-least make sure that all control paths return some value.

As suggested in the below comment by @JonathanLeffler:

```
void mirror(int *arr,int num,int i){
    arr[i] = num % 10;
    if (num >= 10)
        mirror(arr, num / 10, ++i);
}
```

And you're leaking memory horribly. Either `free` memory in each iteration or use a `realloc` and at the end of the program, `free` the memory.

Comment: Damn. Beat me to it.

Comment: Spot on analysis of why the problem.  Minor quibbles about the solution — The return value isn't used; the function could be `void`.  You could simply do: `arr[i] = num % 10; if (num >= 10) mirror(arr, num / 10, ++i);` instead.

Comment: it works fine for num<10 but for num<103 it causes error as it adds extra value to array when num is zero in mirror function

Comment: With the @JonathanLeffler's suggestion, it'll not. [see the code on ideone](http://ideone.com/zrCTqT)

Comment: @AL-zami: if `num >= 10`, then `num / 10` is always at least 1, so the issue of `num == 0` in the recursive calls shouldn't arise.  There are problems if `num` is ever negative, of course.